# Visual tool for browsing LMDB files

Tags: software-recommendation, kubuntu

I am looking for a program that works on Kubuntu and can open and display an LMDB file ([Lightning Memory-Mapped Database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lightning_Memory-Mapped_Database)). Ideally, gratis, can also edit the file, and supports large files, like [HDFView](https://www.hdfgroup.org/products/java/hdfview/) for HDF4 and HDF5 files.

[image]

Comment: That print screen is from a Java programme, which is it? Have you tried to run it on Ubuntu?

Comment: @Luis only works for hdf5 files, not lmdb :(

Comment: You can try https://fastonosql.com